# Using Url Parameters in Rewrite Rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well, I have tried to create a temporary redirect with wildcards:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?topic=1578.0` to `http://www.example.com/demo/showthread.php/1578`

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rules for topics:
RewriteRule ^index.php\?topic=([0-9\.0]+)$ /demo/showthread.php/$1

# Rule for homepage
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /demo/forum.php
```

My problem is with the rules for topics. Simply it does not redirect. Can you guide me the right direction?

Comment: I have read other question, I this is my merge, but I don't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Query String Cannot be Matched Directly in the RewriteRule.**

Use this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} topic=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php /demo/showthread.php/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you, I do know if I am so lost or my question is incorrect. And please apologies if it does.  Is `RewriteRule` a redirection? because the idea is to send the browser to the new url. I am just reiceving the content of the new page but the url is not changing

Comment: I have changed (empirically) the `[L]` by `[R]` and now is working as a champ.

Comment: Yes, `R` will rewrite in the browser, whereas `L` is a transparent redirect. Will update the answer since this is what you want. Once you are happy with the redirect, you can change the `R` to `R=301`. Thank you for the green check mark. :)

Comment: +1 for on the spot **A Query String Cannot be Matched Directly in the RewriteRule**